# Remove incorrect subsequent solutions without once

Tags: prolog, dcg, clpfd

I have a predicate that finds the correct solution but then goes on to find solutions which are not right.

```
?- data(D),data_threshold_nonredundantbumps(D,5,Bs),write(D).
[3,6,7,8,2,4,5,6,9,4,7,3]
D = [3, 6, 7, 8, 2, 4, 5, 6, 9|...],
Bs = [bump([11], [7]), bump([8, 9], [6, 9]), bump([2, 3, 4], [6, 7, 8])] ;
[3,6,7,8,2,4,5,6,9,4,7,3]
D = [3, 6, 7, 8, 2, 4, 5, 6, 9|...],
Bs = [bump([8, 9], [6, 9]), bump([2, 3, 4], [6, 7, 8])] ;
[3,6,7,8,2,4,5,6,9,4,7,3]
D = [3, 6, 7, 8, 2, 4, 5, 6, 9|...],
Bs = [bump([8], [6]), bump([2, 3, 4], [6, 7, 8])] ;
[3,6,7,8,2,4,5,6,9,4,7,3]
D = [3, 6, 7, 8, 2, 4, 5, 6, 9|...],
Bs = [bump([9], [9]), bump([2, 3, 4], [6, 7, 8])] ;
[3,6,7,8,2,4,5,6,9,4,7,3]
D = [3, 6, 7, 8, 2, 4, 5, 6, 9|...],
Bs = [bump([11], [7]), bump([2, 3, 4], [6, 7, 8])] ;
[3,6,7,8,2,4,5,6,9,4,7,3]
D = [3, 6, 7, 8, 2, 4, 5, 6, 9|...],
Bs = [bump([2, 3, 4], [6, 7, 8])] ;
```

etc

The idea is that it will find all the nonredundant bumps in the data, where a bump is a consecutive sublist of `data` that is above `threshold`, Returning an ordered (by size) list of `bump/2s` where the first arg of bump/2 is a list of indicies from data and the second arg is the list of values.  So `bump([2, 3, 4], [6, 7, 8])` means that in data indices 2,3 and 4 are above 5, they are 6,7,8.

How do I add conditions so that these extra solutions are not found? -Without using `once/1`.

If my code could be streamlined in other ways please let me know. It seems a little complicated for what it is trying to do.

So:

Here is my code:

```
:-use_module(library(clpfd)).

fd_length(L, N) :-
 N #>= 0,
 fd_length(L, N, 0).

fd_length([], N, N0) :-
 N #= N0.
fd_length([_|L], N, N0) :-
 N1 is N0+1,
 N #>= N1,
 fd_length(L, N, N1).

equidistant_stride([],_).
equidistant_stride([Z|Zs],D) :-
 foldl(equidistant_stride_(D),Zs,Z,_).

equidistant_stride_(D,Z1,Z0,Z1) :-
 Z1 #= Z0+D.

consecutive_ascending_integers(Zs) :-
 equidistant_stride(Zs,1).

consecutive_ascending_integers_from(Zs,Z0) :-
 Zs = [Z0|_],
 consecutive_ascending_integers(Zs).

bool01_t(1,true).
bool01_t(0,false).

if_(C_1,Then_0,Else_0) -->
 { call(C_1,Truth) },
 { functor(Truth,_,0) },  % safety check
 (  { Truth == true }  -> phrase(Then_0)
 ;  { Truth == false },   phrase(Else_0)
 ).

if_(If_1, Then_0, Else_0) :-
 call(If_1, T),
 (  T == true -> call(Then_0)
 ;  T == false -> call(Else_0)
 ;  nonvar(T) -> throw(error(type_error(boolean,T),_))
 ;  /* var(T) */ throw(error(instantiation_error,_))
 ).


 #=<(X,Y,Truth) :- X #=< Y #<==> B, bool01_t(B,Truth).

 #<( X,Y,Truth) :- X #<  Y #<==> B, bool01_t(B,Truth).

 #>( X,Y,Truth) :- X #>  Y #<==> B, bool01_t(B,Truth).

 #>=(X,Y,Truth) :- X #>= Y #<==> B, bool01_t(B,Truth).

tinclude(P_2,Xs,Zs) :-
 list_tinclude_list(Xs,P_2,Zs).

list_tinclude_list([],   _P_2,[]).
list_tinclude_list([i_v(E0,E1)|Es],P_2,Fs0) :-
 if_(call(P_2,E1), Fs0 = [i_v(E0,E1)|Fs], Fs0 = Fs),
 list_tinclude_list(Es,P_2,Fs).


tfilter(P_2,As,Bs) :-
 tinclude(P_2,As,Bs).

%% =====================================================================
%% =====================================================================

data([5,6,7,8,3,2,6,7]).

list_index_element(L,I,E):-
 nth1(I,L,E).  

filter(Threshold,DataPairs,FilterdPairs):-
 tfilter(#<(Threshold),DataPairs,FilterdPairs).

i_v_pair(I,V,i_v(I,V)).

data_indices_indicespairs(D,Is,Pairs):-
 same_length(D,Is),
 consecutive_ascending_integers_from(Is,1),
 maplist(i_v_pair,Is,D,Pairs).

list_ascending(List,MinLength,MaxLength):-
 Max in MinLength..MaxLength,
 labeling([max(Max)],[Max]),
 fd_length(List,Max),
 consecutive_ascending_integers(List).

region_minlength_maxlength(Region,MinLength,MaxLength,All):-
 list_ascending(Region,MinLength,MaxLength),
 append(_Before,End,All),
 append(Region,_End2,End).

data_threshold_bumpvalues_bumplocation(Data,Threshold,Bumpvalues,Bumplocation):-
 length(Data,MaxBump),
 data_indices_indicespairs(Data,_Is,Pairs),
 filter(Threshold,Pairs,FilteredPairs),
 maplist(i_v_pair,FilteredIndices,_FilteredValues,FilteredPairs),
 %Test =test(FilteredIndexes,FilteredValues),
 dif(Bumplocation,[]),
 region_minlength_maxlength(Bumplocation,0,MaxBump,FilteredIndices),
 maplist(list_index_element(Data), Bumplocation,Bumpvalues).


list_first_last([H|T],H,L):-
 last(T,L).

listoflists_firsts_lasts(Listoflists,Firsts,Lasts):-
 maplist(list_first_last,Listoflists,Firsts,Lasts).

%start is not between location1 and location2
start_location1_location2(Start,Location1,Location2) :-
 #\(   Location1 #=< Start,
 Start #=< Location2).

bumplocation_notsublist_of_any_acs(Bumplocation,Acs):-
 listoflists_firsts_lasts(Acs,Firsts,Lasts),
 %the start of bumplocation can not be between the start of any Acs
 Bumplocation =[Bumpstart|_],
 maplist(start_location1_location2(Bumpstart),Firsts,Lasts).


loc_val_bump(Location,Value,bump(Location,Value)).

data_bumplocations_bumpvalues(Data,Bumplocations,Bumpvalues):-
 maplist(list_index_element(Data),Bumplocations,Bumpvalues).

%this works but finds extra solutins so needs to be refined.
data_threshold_nonredundantbumps(Data,Threshold,Bumps):-
 data_threshold_nonredundantbumps_ac(Data,Threshold,Nonredundantbumpslocations,[]),
 maplist(data_bumplocations_bumpvalues(Data),Nonredundantbumpslocations,Nonredundantbumps),
 maplist(loc_val_bump,Nonredundantbumpslocations,Nonredundantbumps,Bumps).

data_threshold_nonredundantbumps_ac(Data,Threshold,Nonredundantbumps,Ac0):-
 bumplocation_notsublist_of_any_acs(Bumplocation,Ac0),
 data_threshold_bumpvalues_bumplocation(Data,Threshold,_Bumpvalues,Bumplocation),
 append([Bumplocation],Ac0,Ac1),
 data_threshold_nonredundantbumps_ac(Data,Threshold,Nonredundantbumps,Ac1).

data_threshold_nonredundantbumps_ac(_Data,_Threshold,Ac0,Ac0).
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

My impression is that you are overthinking this slightly. There is a straight-forward formulation for **runs** of numbers that exceed the threshold, which can be defined by considering the elements from first to last in a single traversal of the list. In particular, we do **not** need `append/3` to do this.

Always consider using **DCG notation** ([dcg](/questions/tagged/dcg)) when describing *lists* in Prolog. In this case, it takes a moment of reflection to decide how to best apply DCGs, because we are describing *two* lists:

- lists of **runs** (successive elements exceeding the threshold)
- within runs, lists of **indices** and **values**.

However, excepting a few tricks and extensions, a DCG essentially only lets us describe a *single* list, not separate lists at the same time. So, we have this powerful and likely very suitable mechanism at our disposal, and must choose for which kind of list we want to apply it *primarily*.

In the following, I show a solution that uses a DCG to describe a list of **bump/1** terms, that is, I "dedicate" the mechanism to describe the first kind of lists mentioned above, and use another DCG to describe the *second* kind of list, which I invoke via `phrase/2` from within the first DCG.

```
data_threshold_bumps(Ds, T, Bs) :-
        phrase(bumps(Ds, 1, T), Bs).

bumps([], _, _) --> [].
bumps([D|Ds0], I0, T) -->
        { D #> T,
          phrase(bump(D, T, Ds0, Ds, I0, I), Bs) },
        [bump(Bs)],
        bumps(Ds, I, T).
bumps([D|Ds0], I0, T) -->
        { D #=< T,
          I #= I0 + 1 },
        bumps(Ds0, I, T).


bump(D, T, Ds0, Ds, I0, I) --> [I0-D],
        { I1 #= I0 + 1 },
        run(Ds0, Ds, T, I1, I).

run([], [], _, I, I) --> [].
run([D|Ds0], Ds, T, I0, I) --> [I0-D],
        { D #> T,
          I1 #= I0 + 1 },
        run(Ds0, Ds, T, I1, I).
run([D|Ds0], [D|Ds0], T, I, I) -->
        { D #=< T }.
```

Example query and answer:

```
?- data_threshold_bumps([3,6,7,8,2,4,5,6,9,4,7,3], 5, Bs).
Bs = [bump([2-6, 3-7, 4-8]), bump([8-6, 9-9]), bump([11-7])] ;
false.
```

Note that this is not *quite* the exact same data representation that you need, but it is trivial to convert it to that one.

Here are a few ideas to improve upon this solution, from easier to harder:

- Get rid of unnecessary choice-points, using `if_/3`.
- Does it actually make sense to use DCG notation for `bumps//3` and `run//5` in the code above? What are the benefits and drawbacks of using DCGs here over regular predicates?
- Play with different views of the problem: Can you turn the DCG view around? For example, what about describing the actual **data** with a DCG, instead of the bumps?
- Track down the origin(s) of unwanted solutions in the code you posted.

By the way, to *negate* a (reifiable) CLP(FD) constraint, you need to use `(#/\)/2` to denote a conjunction. It does *not* work with `(,)/2`.

Comment: You presumably mean `(',')/2`

Comment: Thanks for the neat solution. Are my unwanted solutions to do with my use of append?  Trying to think about your ideas :)

Comment: Even without having looked into the details of your code, I would say that `append/3` is definitely among the *prime suspects* of generating more answers than we want in this case. Note that frequent use of `append/3` almost always indicates a problem with your data structures: You should either rewrite your algorithm so that you can always reason about the head of your lists (example: `Ls = [First,Second|Rest]`), or use DCGs to describe lists more efficiently.

Comment: One reason I was trying to do this with my clpfd approach, was the possibility of searching for bumps that meet other constraints. For example, all bumps of a certain length, or all bumps whose sum of values are greater than a a number. Would these ideas still be well suited to a dcg formulation?

Comment: Personally, when lists are involved in some way, I almost always use DCG notation to describe them, so, likely yes.

Comment: Thanks again for your advice and expertise.

Answer (score 2):

in the following code, you'll find a number of sections bracketed by

```
:- if(false).
...
:- endif.
```

all these sections get the same result

```
?- data_threshold_bumps([3,6,7,8,2,4,5,6,9,4,7,3], 5, Bs).
Bs = [bump([11], [7]), bump([8, 9], [6, 9]), bump([2, 3, 4], [6, 7, 8])] ;
false.
```

The code itself it's just an application of pattern matching, and, from last to first, show a possible way to refactor the same basic bump/5 predicate to get better readability (but, to be true, my preferred one it's the last one...)

```
data_threshold_bumps(Es, T, Sorted) :-
    bumps(Es, 1, T, Bs),
    predsort(by_len, Bs, Sorted).

bumps([], _, _, []).
bumps([E|Es], P, T, Bs) :-
    succ(P, Q),
    bumps(Es, Q, T, Cs),
    bump(E, P, T, Cs, Bs).

by_len(<, bump(Xs,_), bump(Ys,_)) :-
    length(Xs, Xl),
    length(Ys, Yl), Xl < Yl.
by_len(>, _, _).

:- use_module(library(clpfd)).

bump(E, _, T, Bs, Bs) :- E #=< T.
bump(E, P, T, Cs, Bs) :- E #> T, elem_placed(E, P, Cs, Bs).

elem_placed(E, P, [], [bump([P], [E])]).
elem_placed(E, P, [X|Bs], [Y|Bs]) :-
    X = bump([Q|Ps], [F|Es]),
    P #= Q-1,
    Y = bump([P,Q|Ps], [E,F|Es]).
elem_placed(E, P, [X|Bs], [bump([P],[E]), X|Bs]) :-
    X = bump([Q|_Ps], _Es),
    P #\= Q-1.

:- if(false).

bump(E, _, T, Bs, Bs) :- E =< T.
bump(E, P, T, Cs, Bs) :- E > T, elem_placed(E, P, Cs, Bs).

% first stored: tail
elem_placed(E, P, [], [bump([P], [E])]).
% extend current
elem_placed(E, P, [X|Bs], [Y|Bs]) :-
    X = bump([Q|Ps], [F|Es]),
    succ(P, Q),
    Y = bump([P,Q|Ps], [E,F|Es]).
% place new
elem_placed(E, P, [X|Bs], [bump([P],[E]), X|Bs]) :-
    X = bump([Q|_Ps], _Es),
    \+ succ(P, Q).

:- endif.

:- if(false).

bump(E, _, T, Bs, Bs) :- E =< T.
bump(E, P, T, Cs, Bs) :- E > T, enabled(E, P, Cs, Bs).

enabled(E, P, [], [bump([P], [E])]).
enabled(E, P, [bump([Q|Ps], [F|Es])|Bs], [bump([P,Q|Ps], [E,F|Es])|Bs]) :- succ(P, Q).
enabled(E, P, [bump([Q|Ps], [F|Es])|Bs], [bump([P],[E]), bump([Q|Ps],[F|Es])|Bs]) :- \+ succ(P, Q).

:- endif.

:- if(false).

bump(E, _, T, Bs, Bs) :- E =< T.
bump(E, P, T, [], [bump([P], [E])]) :- E > T.
bump(E, P, T, [bump([Q|Ps], [F|Es])|Bs], [bump([P,Q|Ps], [E,F|Es])|Bs]) :- E > T, succ(P, Q).
bump(E, P, T, [bump([Q|Ps], [F|Es])|Bs], [bump([P],[E]), bump([Q|Ps],[F|Es])|Bs]) :- E > T, \+ succ(P, Q).

:- endif.
```

Comment: Clever use of conditional compilation directives.