# Applying semicontext for passing additional arguments

Tags: prolog, dcg, implicit-state-passing, dcg-semicontext

This is a follow-on question from an earlier [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42672512/1243762) from Mat's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42722823/1243762)

Starting with this

```erlang
e([number(0)]           , t1        , Uc0    , Uc0, Bc0    , Bc0) --> [].
e([number(1)]           , t2        , Uc0    , Uc0, Bc0    , Bc0) --> [].
e([number(2)]           , t3        , Uc0    , Uc0, Bc0    , Bc0) --> [].

e([op(neg),[Arg]]       , u1(E)     , [_|Uc0], Uc1, Bc0    , Bc1) --> 
    [_],   
    e(Arg , E , Uc0, Uc1, Bc0, Bc1).
e([op(ln),[Arg]]        , u2(E)     , [_|Uc0], Uc1, Bc0    , Bc1) --> 
    [_],   
    e(Arg , E , Uc0, Uc1, Bc0, Bc1).

e([op(add),[Left,Right]], b1(E0,E1) , Uc0    , Uc2, [_|Bc0], Bc2) --> 
    [_,_], 
    e(Left, E0, Uc0, Uc1, Bc0, Bc1), 
    e(Right, E1, Uc1, Uc2, Bc1, Bc2).
e([op(sub),[Left,Right]], b2(E0,E1) , Uc0    , Uc2, [_|Bc0], Bc2) --> 
    [_,_], 
    e(Left, E0, Uc0, Uc1, Bc0, Bc1), 
    e(Right, E1, Uc1, Uc2, Bc1, Bc2).

e(U,B,EL,Es) :-
    length(UL, U),
    length(BL, B),
    phrase(e(EL,Es,UL,[],BL,[]), _).

e(N,EL,Es) :-
    length([_|Ls], N),
    phrase(e(EL,Es,_,[],_,[]),Ls).

e_count(E, Count) :-
    length([_|Ls], E),
    findall(., phrase(e(_,_,_,[],_,[]), Ls), Sols),
    length(Sols, Count).
```

then reading

> For one variable, use a list with a single element that contains just
>   that variable. If you want to pass around more than one variable, use
>   a list that contains a single term of the form f(...), capturing all
>   variables you want to pass around. This is also well worth its
>   own question.

evolved into this

```erlang
e( f([number(0)], t1, Uc0, Uc0, Bc0, Bc0) ) --> [].
e( f([number(1)], t2, Uc0, Uc0, Bc0, Bc0) ) --> [].
e( f([number(2)], t3, Uc0, Uc0, Bc0, Bc0) ) --> [].

e( f([op(neg), [Arg]], u1(E), [_|Uc0], Uc1, Bc0, Bc1) ) --> 
    [_], 
    e( f(Arg, E, Uc0, Uc1, Bc0, Bc1) ).
e( f([op(ln) , [Arg]], u2(E), [_|Uc0], Uc1, Bc0, Bc1) ) --> 
    [_], 
    e( f(Arg, E, Uc0, Uc1, Bc0, Bc1) ).

e( f([op(add), [Left,Right]], b1(E0,E1) ,Uc0, Uc2, [_|Bc0], Bc2) ) --> 
    [_,_], 
    e(f(Left, E0, Uc0, Uc1, Bc0, Bc1) ), 
    e(f(Right, E1, Uc1, Uc2, Bc1, Bc2) ).
e( f([op(sub), [Left,Right]], b2(E0,E1) ,Uc0, Uc2, [_|Bc0], Bc2) ) --> 
    [_,_],
    e(f(Left, E0, Uc0, Uc1, Bc0, Bc1) ),
    e(f(Right, E1, Uc1, Uc2, Bc1, Bc2) ).

e(U,B,EL,Es) :-
    length(UL, U),
    length(BL, B),
    phrase(e(f(EL,Es,UL,[],BL,[])), _).

e_N(N,EL,Es) :-
    length([_|Ls], N),
    phrase(e(f(EL,Es,_,[],_,[])),Ls).

e_count(E, Count) :-
    length([_|Ls], E),
    findall(., phrase(e(f(_,_,_,[],_,[])), Ls), Sols),
    length(Sols, Count).
```

which *works* but it is noted `use a list that contains a single term of the form f(...)`, and here `f(...)` is not in a list.

Did I go wrong somewhere?

### Supplement

### References

- [Thinking in States](https://www.metalevel.at/tist/) by Markus Triska
- [Prolog DCG Primer](https://www.metalevel.at/prolog/dcg) by Markus Triska
- [Extra Arguments](http://www.learnprolognow.org/lpnpage.php?pagetype=html&pageid=lpn-htmlse32) with Learn Prolog Now!

### Variable names convention with implicit state passing

Normally when using [implict-state-passing](/questions/tagged/implict-state-passing) the variables are named

`S0` →  `S1` →…→ `S`

However for my uniary-binary tree examples I name them like

`S0` → `S1` →…→ `Sn`

ending with `Sn` instead of `S`.

e.g.

standard

```erlang
e(S0,S) :-
```

here

```erlang
 e(S0,S2) :-
```

the reason being that this example has a rather rare property of each DCG predicate having increasing length,

e.g.

```erlang
e([number(0)]           , t1        , Uc0    , Uc0, Bc0    , Bc0) -->  
e([op(neg),[Arg]]       , u1(E)     , [_|Uc0], Uc1, Bc0    , Bc1) -->   
e([op(add),[Left,Right]], b1(E0,E1) , Uc0    , Uc2, [_|Bc0], Bc2) -->
```

so ending with `xn` gives me one more check on accuracy.

Reference: [ISO/IEC DTR 13211–3:2006 Deﬁnite clause grammar rules](http://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/ulrich/iso-prolog/dcgs/dcgsdraft-2015-11-10.pdf)

> 6.1.3 Variable names convention for terminal-sequences
>
> This TR uses variables named S0, S1, ..., S to represent the terminal-sequences 
>   used as arguments when processing grammar rules or when expanding
>   grammar rules into clauses. In this notation, the variables S0, S1,
>   ..., S can be regarded as a sequence of states, with S0 representing
>   the initial state and the variable S representing the ﬁnal state.
>   Thus, if the variable Si represents the terminal-sequence in a given
>   state, the variable Si+1 will represent the remaining
>   terminal-sequence after parsing Si with a grammar rule.

Comment: Don't really see the title as good fit for the question so if you know of a better one, please change it.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand the question. Did you mean to write "canonical" instead of "conical?"

Comment: @AndersonGreen Like I noted in a comment it is a bad title. You really have to read mat's answer to a previous question which is linked and then read the quote here to fully understand this question. It is more a pretext so mat can expand on the previous question since the previous question was getting way to large.

Comment: @GuyCoder: Why not just semicontext?

Comment: @GuyCoder: For the tag

Comment: @false I didn't know `semicontext notation` had a name until I read mat's answer. Then I found it explained in Markus Triska's DCG document. Since both used `Semicontext notation` together and emphasized that is what I used. We can always create a [tag synonym](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/synonyms?filter=all&tab=newest). I have tried to make a few tag synonyms but it appears there are some conditions necessary before one can make a synonym, I believe 5 points for the tag, so I haven't been able to make the ones I want.

Comment: @false Since there are very few questions tagged with 'semicontext-notation` we can make the synonym and retag the exiting tagged questions before it becomes epidemic.

Comment: @false I see; I found [ISO/IEC DTR 13211–3:2006 Deﬁnite clause grammar rules](http://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/ulrich/iso-prolog/dcgs/dcgsdraft-2015-11-10.pdf)

Comment: In man programming languages there  is no if-notation, nor a  while-loop-notation. It's just an if, or an if-statement etc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A DCG *always* describes a *list*.

But *which* list? **You have to decide how to dedicate the mechanism**!

In the above cases, it seems *you have already dedicated* DCGs to describe a *list* whose length you use as a measure for the depth of the search.

That's completely OK, and a very natural use of DCGs.

However, you can only describe *one list*, not two at the same time, at least not in the "primary" way. You can of course describe arbitrarily many terms at the same time via DCG *arguments*. However, the DCG *body* is limited to describing just *one* list, by invoking nonterminals, and using terminals.

There is a straight-forward way to convert DCGs to regular Prolog code *without* DCGs, or to interpret DCG rules via regular Prolog. See for example the ISO draft for more information.

For example, let us take just this snippet:

```
e( f([op(neg), [Arg]], u1(E), [_|Uc0], Uc1, Bc0, Bc1) ) --> 
    [_], 
    e( f(Arg, E, Uc0, Uc1, Bc0, Bc1) ).
e( f([op(ln) , [Arg]], u2(E), [_|Uc0], Uc1, Bc0, Bc1) ) --> 
    [_], 
    e( f(Arg, E, Uc0, Uc1, Bc0, Bc1) ).
```

Let's get rid of the DCG syntax, and write it *for example* as:

```
e( f([op(neg), [Arg]], u1(E), [_|Uc0], Uc1, Bc0, Bc1, [_|Rest0], Rest) ) :- 
    e( f(Arg, E, Uc0, Uc1, Bc0, Bc1, Rest0, Rest) ).
e( f([op(ln) , [Arg]], u2(E), [_|Uc0], Uc1, Bc0, Bc1, [_|Rest0], Rest) ) :- 
    e( f(Arg, E, Uc0, Uc1, Bc0, Bc1, Rest0, Rest) ).
```

(Note of course that you *should not* rely on any particular expansion method, but always use the `phrase/2` interface to invoke a DCG. Still, the above is *one* way to perform such an expansion, obtaining regular Prolog code.)

## Switching arguments

Suppose we want to go *back* to using DCG notation again, because it is so convenient. For example, we obviously need to think about *fewer variables* when using DCG notation, and that can in itself already be a huge advantage.

So, we can of course go back to our initial DCG, using terminals instead of our last two new arguments that we introduced to describe a list difference.

But we can also do *something else*!

For example, in the snippet above, we note that `Bc0` and `Bc1` are **only threaded through**: None of the clauses really cares about these arguments. So, suppose we dedicate the DCG mechanism to describe *these two* arguments.

This could for example look as follows:

```
e( f([op(neg), [Arg]], u1(E), [_|Uc0], Uc1, [_|Rest0], Rest) ) -->
    e( f(Arg, E, Uc0, Uc1, Rest0, Rest) ).
e( f([op(ln) , [Arg]], u2(E), [_|Uc0], Uc1, [_|Rest0], Rest) ) -->
    e( f(Arg, E, Uc0, Uc1, Rest0, Rest) ).
```

Here, I have started from the regular Prolog version, introduced DCG notation, and simply turned `Bc0` and `Bc1` into the *implicit* arguments! They no longer appear *at all* here. Only if we again expand this back into Prolog do they become visible, or at least that's *one* way to do it.

**But**, there are two problems that remain:

First, what if we actually *want to access* these arguments? Certainly not *all* clauses only thread them through like this. We also need to *access* them somewhere. And second, there's an even more fundamental problem: We want to talk about a single argument, which can be *any term*, but DCGs always describe a *list*!

So, how do we reconcile all this?

Most importantly, we need to talk about lists, so the solution is simple: Let us talk about **a list with a single element**, i.e., the list `[Bc0]` and `[Bc1]`. This makes DCG notation applicable *at all* in this case.

Next, how do we express the relation between `Bc0` and `Bc1` within the DCG? For this, we use **semicontext notation**: It lets as talk about elements that previously *were not in the list* we are describing.

As noted in the DCG primer, a nonterminal of the following form will be useful:

```
state(S0, S), [S] --> [S0].
```

You can read the nonterminal `state(S0, S)` as: The current state is `S0`, and *henceforth* it is `S`.

Thus, *if* you want to actually access `Bc0` and relate it to `Bc1` in one of your clauses, you could do it like this:

```
e( f([op(neg), [Arg]], u1(E), [_|Uc0], Uc1, [_|Rest0], Rest) ) -->
    state(Bc0, Bc1),
    ... (something involving Bc0 and Bc1) ...
    e( f(Arg, E, Uc0, Uc1, Rest0, Rest) ).
```

The major advantage is this: This notation lets you *hide* the additional arguments, and *still* lets you access them explicitly *if you need it*, using `state//2` (or semicontext notation directly).

This obviously becomes more and more attractive *the less the arguments are actually used* in your code. If almost all of your clauses access the arguments, there is no sense in hiding them. However, quite frequently, you will describe terms that are threaded through while only very few of your DCG clauses actually access them. In such cases, consider using DCG notation to pass them around implicitly.

But there's still one problem: What to do if we want to pass around not only *one* term, but two or more? There's a very easy solution for this: Let us still pass around a list with a single element, but let that element simply be a *compound term* of the form `f(Arg1,Arg2,...,Arg_n)`. Thus, your invocation of your nonterminal `e//N` might look like this:

```
?- phrase(e(Arg1,Arg2,...,Arg_N), [f(B1,B2,...,B_M)], [Result]).
```

Here, `B1`, `B2` etc. are the arguments that you would like to pass around *implicitly*, in the form of a list with a single element that combines all these arguments.

Assuming this answers your question, a suitable title could be: "Applying semicontext notation for passing additional arguments". The actual question makes clear, and I think that is critical in this case, that you want to apply semicontext notation for passing additional arguments *even though you have already dedicated the DCG notation to describe something else*. To summarize, a solution for this is to first free the DCG notation so that you can use the described list for passing around additional arguments.

Note that there are also other solutions: For example, you can devise your *own* custom notation, completely analogous to DCG notation, but expanded in such a way that it lets you describe *two independent lists* at the same time. I leave this as an exercise.

Comment: Thanks. I will tinker with this.

Comment: I think it's definitely good to have a tag for it! I can imagine that [tag:semicontext] can be interpreted more generally and could therefore be useful in more situations than "only" [tag:semicontext-notation].